# Cocoa pods with Swift 1.2 bridging header comples, but ViewController can't find type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently migrating over to Swift 1.2, and am currently using the `use_frameworks!` flag in cocoapods in order to accomodate Alamofire. Pods installs correctly, and the compiler complained that the bridging header couldn't find headers that were declared as:

`#import "ThirdPartyLibraryClass.h"`

so I updated to

`#import <ThirdPartyLibraryClass/ThirdPartyLibraryClass.h>`

the compiler stopped complaining, but can't find the types when building

Comment: Is it a typo in this question or did you have this exact first import statement? Because it's missing the quotes: `#import "ThirdPartyLibraryClass.h"`

Comment: it was just the way I typed it in stack, edited now haha.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Select your project, go to:

*BuildSettings - searchPath - User header search path:*

[image]

Now enter this value for debug and/or release:  ***“Pods/**”***

Comment: added it for both, but nothing changed

Comment: Does your problem concern Alamonfire?

Comment: It does not. I didn't know if the use_frameworks! flag may have anything to do it with it though. Alamofire was the first pod I've used that required it

Comment: Unfortunatly, i don't use cocoapod for swift libraries, I just copy the code folder in my project.

Comment: Thanks for the effort though!